# I want to update apps on playstore

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello  I have already publish apps on playstore. now i want to update my apps but when i upload new apk on playstore then this error on the apps

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: D7:19:FF:14:28:CE:F5:77:EA:38:58:D8:6F:A2:4C:2C:6A:2A:F1:9D ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 19:FA:4A:3C:1B:58:BB:81:D3:1E:3C:81:72:D1:A2:71:9B:3D:92:3C ]

please give me solution for that

Comment: Are you sure , you are using same keystore?

Comment: have you used previous keystore to sign new apk

Comment: See the official docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1):

An application published to the play store *must* be signed with the same key.  There is no way around this requirement and why it is paramount that you secure your key in a place that it 1) will not be compromised and 2) never be lost ;)

Comment: so now what was solution.??

Comment: Sign the app with the same keystore you previously used.  There is no other solution.  If you no longer have that keystore then you must publish a new app with a new package.